# Why function is not working asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to learn asynchronous programming and having learnt the basic tried following codes. One code works asynchronously however the other doesn't could someone please help identifying the difference?

**Code doesn't work asynchronously:**

```
   public  static async Task FunctionAsync(int a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method with {0}:", a + " seconds started.");
        await Task.Delay(a * 1000);
        Console.WriteLine("\nMethod with {0}:", a + " seconds completed.");
    }

    public static async Task CallMethodAsync()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        List<Func<Task>> list = new List<Func<Task>>();
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        list.Add(() => FunctionAsync(random.Next(1, 10)));
        list.Add(() => FunctionAsync(random.Next(1, 10)));
        list.Add(() => FunctionAsync(random.Next(1, 10)));
        list.Add(() => FunctionAsync(random.Next(1, 10)));
        list.Add(() => FunctionAsync(random.Next(1, 10)));

        stopwatch.Start();

        foreach (var item in list)
            await item();

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Total time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
    }
```

**Code works asynchronously:**

```
public  static async Task FunctionAsync(int a)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Method with {0}:", a + " seconds started.");
    await Task.Delay(a * 1000);
    Console.WriteLine("\nMethod with {0}:", a + " seconds completed.");
}

public static async Task CallMethodAsync()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    stopwatch.Start();

    tasks.Add(FunctionAsync(random.Next(1, 10)));
    tasks.Add(FunctionAsync(random.Next(1, 10)));
    tasks.Add(FunctionAsync(random.Next(1, 10)));
    tasks.Add(FunctionAsync(random.Next(1, 10)));
    tasks.Add(FunctionAsync(random.Next(1, 10)));

    foreach (var item in tasks)
        await item;

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    stopwatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Total time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
}
```

Comment: What do you think the `()` after `item` in your first example signify?

Comment: Because of this line: `await item();`, you haven't called the functions yet, and in this version of the code you call the first function, then wait for **that task** to complete, and only afterwards do you call the next function and wait for its task. In the second version you "start" each task first, when you add them, and then afterwards you're just waiting for them to complete.

Comment: Yes - in the second version you're iterating over *tasks that have already started*. You're calling the asynchronous method while you're adding items to the list, and they're starting at that point.

Comment: @JonSkeet isn't that the case in first version? Then why asynchronous method doesn't get called when adding to the list? Asking for better understanding?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I understood this part " you call the first function, then wait for that task to complete, and only afterwards do you call the next function and wait for its task". However, I'm doing the same thing in working version of code, what's the difference there? In first version I'm iterating over List<Func<Task>> where as in second version iterating over List<Task>

Comment: No, it's not. In the first version, as per Lasse's comment, when you've finished building the list you haven't *called* the `FunctionAsync` method at all. So nothing's been started. In the second version, when you've finished building the list, you've called the method 5 times, and so you've started 5 tasks.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, so how do we get the first version working asynchronously with list of Func<Task> or List<Acton>?

Comment: I suggest that now you (hopefully) understand what's going on, you think about what you're trying to achieve. All we can see is the code - we don't know what your actual purpose is. Once you've decided the bigger purpose, you can try to achieve it using your new understanding - and if you still can't get it to work, you can ask a new question showing what you've tried and - most importantly - describing clearly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, consider there is a very big batch of files (50k+) and our function can only process 10K files, so we break this large batch in sub-batch (at run time) of 10k and hand it over to the function for processing. Now the number of functions that should run asynchronously depends on the size of large batch. So, in case of 50K files there should be 5 functions run asynchronously, for 80k files 8 functions run asynchronously. So that's what I was trying to do by using List<Func<Task>> instead of List<Task>, any suggestions?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's for calling the function

Comment: @Aniruddha: No, I didn't suggest putting details that should be in a question into comments. I suggested going away to think about it, trying it for yourself, and asking a new question if you get stuck.